# Gridview.Rows.count in multi page Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a GridView that the paging is true and I want to take the number of rows but only the number of rows to page 1 return,

```
Gridview.Rows.count
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for the total amount of rows on a specific page?

If so you shouldn't be trying to find that information from the `GridView` but instead look at the underlying `DataSource` that you bound your `GridView` to.

Eg.

```
 List<SomeObjects> lst = GetYourData();
 yourGrid.DataSource = lst;
 yourGrid.DataBind();

 // if you want to get the count for a specific page
 int currentPage = 2;
 int countForPage2 = (lst.Count > currentPage * totalItemsPerPage)) ?
     totalItemsPerPage : lst.Count - ((currentPage - 1) * totalItemsPerPage);
```